# Clean up dirty xml string with RegExp - c#

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

i have the following xml string:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>\r\n<axeed>\r\n  <FIELD name=\"QV_KEY\" label=\"Key\" type=\"label\" size=\"80\"></FIELD>\r\n  <FIELD name=\"Id\" label=\"ID\" type=\"hidden\"></FIELD>\r\n  <FIELD name=\"ITEM_1\" label=\"Comment\" type=\"textarea\" rows=\"5\" cols=\"60\" tooltyp=\"1\"></FIELD>\r\n  <FIELD name=\"ITEM_2\" label=\"Public\" type=\"checkbox\"></FIELD>\r\n  <FIELD name=\"ITEM_4\" label=\"Revision Date\" type=\"date\" format=\"dd.mm.yyyy\"
```

I would like to clean it up without any:

- \r
- \n
- \

The output should be like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><axeed>  <FIELD name="QV_KEY" label="Key" type="label" size="80"></FIELD>  <FIELD name="Id" label="ID" type="hidden"></FIELD>  <FIELD name="ITEM_1" label="Comment" type="textarea" rows="5" cols="60" tooltyp="1"></FIELD>  <FIELD name="ITEM_2" label="Public" type="checkbox"></FIELD>  <FIELD name="ITEM_4" label="Revision Date" type="date" format="dd.mm.yy">
```

Can I solve it with a regular expression?

Regards,
Patric

Comment: Just replace them? Doesn't look to me (judging by your examples) like you're doing anything that would require a parse or decode. HINT: Remove `\r` and `\n` before you remove `\\`.

Comment: I used the following reg expression Regex.Replace(xmlData, @"\t|\n|\r", ""); but the single back slash still remains even if i do soemthing like that after this statement: xml.Replace(Replace("\"", xmlData);

Comment: You're over-complicating it. You don't need regex.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using the reqexpression:

Regex.Replace(xmlData, @"\t|\n|\r", "");

The other back slash character are produced by Visual Studio, it is just a visual thing.